# Arch linux ati graphics crash after grub install

Tags: grub, arch-linux, gnome3, amd-graphics-card

Ok, so I've had an arch linux w/ gnome 3 installed for a while now. And a while ago I installed ubuntu as another partition, I think to fix an issue that cause arch to fail.

So, it was all working fine, but then I went and reinstalled grub 1 on the arch partition;
Ubuntu had overwritten it on the install.

Then when I tried to boot into arch it booted, but the graphics wasn't working correctly: gdm wouldn't even show, and there were weird colors instead. So, I uninstalled xf86-video-ati and then installed xf86-video-vesa. That made gdm run in fallback mode and I was able to boot to gnome 3 fallback mode (or whatever it's called).

But I can't seem to get the graphics working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I did fix it. I'm guessing it was a driver issue, because when I upgraded to the newest driver it started working again. It is possible that the previous build was broken in some way.

Answer (score 2):

you'd better paste the message in **/var/log/Xorg.0.log**.

can you startx in **root** ?

if so,you can try this:

1. make sure *gdm* is in **DAEMON** in **/etc/rc.conf**
2. `$ cp ~/.xinitrc ~/.xinitrc.bak`
3. `$ echo "exec ck-launch-session gnome-session" > ~/.xinitrc`